# Happy Community Manager Appreciation Day

Tags: discussion

Happy [Community Manager Appreciation Day](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Community_Manager_Appreciation_Day) to everyone who participates in the self management of the SFSE!  (Special shout out to the [moderators](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) @metadaddy, @LaceysSnr, @Saariko!).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I definitely concur! You guys rock!

https://twitter.com/jessealtman/status/427842217902755842

Comment: ^^ you rock! Without the amazing users and participation , we had nothing to mod. So, thank you